# Joint density of Markov process as product of conditional densities.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(X(t))_{t\geq0}$ be a Markov proces such that s $X(0)=x_0$. Consider the random vector $(X(t_1),\dots,X(t_n))$ with corresponding joint density $g(x_1,\dots ,x_n)$. Is it then true that $g(x_1,\dots x_n)=p(0,t_1,x_0,x_1)\cdot p(t_1,t_2,x_1,x_2)  \cdots  p(t_{n-1},t_n,x_{n-1},x_n)$ where $p(a,b,c,d)$ is the corresponding transition density between time a to b and state c to d.

If so I would love a proof or a reference. I know a bit of theory about Markov processes, but am not perfectly comfortable with transition densities. I tried proving it just using the Markov property, but without  great success.

Comment: The obvious: iterate [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Transition_probability_definition).

Comment: Will this work with an uncountable state space?

Comment: Why not? (Say, you erased a comment, no?)

Comment: Is the left hand side not just 0 always? I thought I understood it (indicated it in a comment), worked with it and suddenly I felt indicating that I understood it was a bit misleading :)

Comment: Hmmm... how do you define p(t,s,x,y) in the first place? The trouble you have seems to come from undigested aspects of THAT.

Comment: I've only seen it for time homogeneous Markov Chains in $\mathbb{R}^d$ I think, but a kernel [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel) is a transition density for a Markov process if $P_t(x,\mathbb{R}^d)=1$, $P_{t+s}(x,A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P_t(y,A)P_s(x,dy)$ and $P_t(x,A)=\mathbb{P}^x (X_t \in A)$ where $(X_t,\mathbb{P}^x)$ is the Markov process.

Comment: Right. And which mysteries remain?

Comment: Consider the Markov process given by a Brownian motion (0 in 0) then $P(X(t)=x|X(0)=0)=P(X(t)=x)=0$ for any $x$. But surely $P_t(0,x)$ is not identically equal to zero for any x.

Comment: Confusing probabilities and densities? See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The question might be based on a confusion between transition *probabilities* and transition *densities*.

In the first case the conditional distribution of $X(t+s)$ conditionally on $\mathcal F_s=\sigma(X(u);u\leqslant s)$ is such that
$$
P[X(t+s)=y\mid X(s)=x,\mathcal F_s]=p(s,t+s,x,y),
$$
for every states $(x,y)$. Thus, every entry $p(s,t+s,x,y)$ is nonnegative and, for every $x$,
$$
\sum_yp(s,t+s,x,y)=1.
$$
This implies that, for every $x$, the set $\{y\mid p(s,t+s,x,y)\ne0\}$ is at most countable.

In the second case the conditional distribution of $X(t+s)$ conditionally on $\mathcal F_s$ is such that
$$
P[X(t+s)\in B\mid X(s)=x,\mathcal F_s]=\int_Bp(s,t+s,x,y)\mathrm dy,
$$
for every state $x$ and every (measurable) set $B$. Since the conditional distribution of $X(t+s)$ is absolutely continuous, for every $y$,
$$
P[X(t+s)=y\mid X(s)=x,\mathcal F_s]=0,
$$
but it may well happen that $\{y\mid p(s,t+s,x,y)\ne0\}$ is the whole state space, even when said state space is uncountable.